# Creating an (VB) APP and it isnt working correctly

Tags: vb.net

I am at college and am creating an app. however i have two main problems within my app. my app is a pizza app which will allow staff within a pizza shop to send the orders to the kitchen (this is just a listbox). but, the math doesnt work, the correct pricing isnt being displayed in the label for the orders for some reason. I have tried different ways of writing and placing my code but the result is always the same. also, i have five customers per table. if i select all the customers orders and click on send, only customer two's order will be sent. not any of the other customers, but if i just do customer one on its own, it works.

Below is my code, hopefully someone will be able to tell me where i am going wrong because i think im just being blind as ive looked through the whole thing and cant see a problem with it. Thanks in advance for any given help/feedback to the solution.

APP Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim myformat As String = "{0,-10}{1,-25}{2,-15}{3,-30}{4,-10}"
    Dim cost As Single
    Dim base As String
    Dim pizza As String
    Dim table As String
    Dim topping As String
    Dim drink As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(myformat, "table", "pizza", "base", "topping", "drink"))
    End Sub
    Private Sub STK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles STK.Click


    '------------------table no-------------------'
    If tableno.Text = "1" Then
        table = "1"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "2" Then
        table = "2"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "3" Then
        table = "3"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "4" Then
        table = "4"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "5" Then
        table = "5"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "6" Then
        table = "6"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "7" Then
        table = "7"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "8" Then
        table = "8"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "9" Then
        table = "9"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "10" Then
        table = "10"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "11" Then
        table = "11"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "12" Then
        table = "12"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "13" Then
        table = "13"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "14" Then
        table = "14"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "15" Then
        table = "15"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "16" Then
        table = "16"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "17" Then
        table = "17"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "18" Then
        table = "18"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "19" Then
        table = "19"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "20" Then
        table = "20"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "21" Then
        table = "21"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "22" Then
        table = "22"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "23" Then
        table = "23"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "24" Then
        table = "24"
    ElseIf tableno.Text = "25" Then
        table = "25"
    End If
    '---------------pizza type 1----------------'
    If pizza1.Text = "Planet Cheese" Then
        pizza = "Planet Cheese"
        cost = 4.0
    ElseIf pizza1.Text = "Planet Special" Then
        pizza = "Planet Special"
        cost = 5.0
    ElseIf pizza1.Text = "Planet Vegi" Then
        pizza = "Planet Vegi"
        cost = 4.5
    ElseIf pizza1.Text = "Planet Feast" Then
        pizza = "Planet Feast"
        cost = 6.0
    ElseIf pizza1.Text = "Planet Itella" Then
        pizza = "Planet Itella"
        cost = 6.5
    End If
    '---------------pizza type 2----------------'
    If pizza2.Text = "Planet Cheese" Then
        pizza = "Planet Cheese"
        cost = 4.0
    ElseIf pizza2.Text = "Planet Special" Then
        pizza = "Planet Special"
        cost = 5.0
    ElseIf pizza2.Text = "Planet Vegi" Then
        pizza = "Planet Vegi"
        cost = 4.5
    ElseIf pizza2.Text = "Planet Feast" Then
        pizza = "Planet Feast"
        cost = 6.0
    ElseIf pizza2.Text = "Planet Itella" Then
        pizza = "Planet Itella"
        cost = 6.5
    End If


    '---------------pizza type 3----------------'
    If pizza3.Text = "Planet Cheese" Then
        pizza = "Planet Cheese"
        cost = 4.0
    ElseIf pizza3.Text = "Planet Special" Then
        pizza = "Planet Special"
        cost = 5.0
    ElseIf pizza3.Text = "Planet Vegi" Then
        pizza = "Planet Vegi"
        cost = 4.5
    ElseIf pizza3.Text = "Planet Feast" Then
        pizza = "Planet Feast"
        cost = 6.0
    ElseIf pizza3.Text = "Planet Itella" Then
        pizza = "Planet Itella"
        cost = 6.5
    End If

    '---------------pizza type 4----------------'
    If pizza4.Text = "Planet Cheese" Then
        pizza = "Cheese and Tamato"
        cost = 4.0
    ElseIf pizza4.Text = "Planet Special" Then
        pizza = "Planet Special"
        cost = 5.0
    ElseIf pizza4.Text = "Planet Vegi" Then
        pizza = "Planet Vegi"
        cost = 4.5
    ElseIf pizza4.Text = "Planet Feast" Then
        pizza = "Planet Feast"
        cost = 6.0
    ElseIf pizza4.Text = "Planet Itella" Then
        pizza = "Planet Itella"
        cost = 6.5
    End If

    '---------------pizza type 5----------------'
    If pizza5.Text = "Planet Cheese" Then
        pizza = "Planet Cheese"
        cost = 4.0
    ElseIf pizza2.Text = "Planet Special" Then
        pizza = "Planet Special"
        cost = 5.0
    ElseIf pizza5.Text = "Planet Vegi" Then
        pizza = "Planet Vegi"
        cost = 4.5
    ElseIf pizza2.Text = "Planet Feast" Then
        pizza = "Planet Feast"
        cost = 6.0
    ElseIf pizza5.Text = "Planet Itella" Then
        pizza = "Planet Itella"
        cost = 6.5
    End If


    '---------------base 1 ------------'
    If norm1.Checked Then
        base = "norm"
    ElseIf thin1.Checked Then
        base = "thin"
    ElseIf CB1.Checked Then
        base = "CB"
    ElseIf BSC1.Checked Then
        base = "BSC"
    End If
    '---------------base 2 ------------'
    If norm2.Checked Then
        base = "norm"
    ElseIf thin2.Checked Then
        base = "thin"
    ElseIf CB2.Checked Then
        base = "CB"
    ElseIf BSC2.Checked Then
        base = "BSC"
    End If
    '---------------base 3 ------------'
    If norm3.Checked Then
        base = "norm"
    ElseIf thin3.Checked Then
        base = "thin"
    ElseIf CB3.Checked Then
        base = "CB"
    ElseIf BSC3.Checked Then
        base = "BSC"
    End If
    '---------------base 4 ------------'
    If norm4.Checked Then
        base = "norm"
    ElseIf thin4.Checked Then
        base = "thin"
    ElseIf CB4.Checked Then
        base = "CB"
    ElseIf BSC4.Checked Then
        base = "BSC"
    End If
    '---------------base 5 ------------'
    If norm5.Checked Then
        base = "norm"
    ElseIf thin5.Checked Then
        base = "thin"
    ElseIf CB5.Checked Then
        base = "CB"
    ElseIf BSC5.Checked Then
        base = "BSC"
    End If





    '----------topping1----'
    If cheese1.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Cheese"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If pepperoni1.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Pepperoni"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If onion1.Checked = True Then
        topping = "onion"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If peppers1.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Peppers"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If sausage1.Checked = True Then
        topping = "sausage"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If tuna1.Checked = True Then
        topping = "tuna"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If meatballs1.Checked = True Then
        topping = "meatballs"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If






    '----------topping2----'
    If cheese2.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Cheese"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If pepperoni2.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Pepperoni"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If onion2.Checked = True Then
        topping = "onion"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If peppers2.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Peppers"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If sausage2.Checked = True Then
        topping = "sausage"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If tuna2.Checked = True Then
        topping = "tuna"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If meatballs2.Checked = True Then
        topping = "meatballs"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If





    '----------topping3----'
    If cheese3.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Cheese"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If pepperoni3.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Pepperoni"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If onion3.Checked = True Then
        topping = "onion"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If peppers3.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Peppers"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If sausage3.Checked = True Then
        topping = "sausage"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If tuna3.Checked = True Then
        topping = "tuna"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If meatballs3.Checked = True Then
        topping = "meatballs"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If






    '----------topping4----'
    If cheese4.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Cheese"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If pepperoni4.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Pepperoni"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If onion4.Checked = True Then
        topping = "onion"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If peppers4.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Peppers"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If sausage4.Checked = True Then
        topping = "sausage"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If tuna4.Checked = True Then
        topping = "tuna"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If meatballs4.Checked = True Then
        topping = "meatballs"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If







    '----------topping5----'
    If cheese5.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Cheese"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If pepperoni5.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Pepperoni"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If onion5.Checked = True Then
        topping = "onion"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If peppers5.Checked = True Then
        topping = "Peppers"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If sausage5.Checked = True Then
        topping = "sausage"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If tuna5.Checked = True Then
        topping = "tuna"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If
    If meatballs5.Checked = True Then
        topping = "meatballs"
        cost = cost + 1.0
    End If







    '---------------drink1-----------------------'
    If drink1.Text = "Cola" Then
        drink = "Cola"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Fruit Punch" Then
        drink = "Fruit Punch"
        cost = cost + 0.8
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "J2o" Then
        drink = "J2o"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Alien Blaster" Then
        drink = "Alien Blaster"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Alien Brains" Then
        drink = "Alien Brains"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    End If





    '---------------drink2-----------------------'
    If drink2.Text = "Cola" Then
        drink = "Cola"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink2.Text = "Fruit Punch" Then
        drink = "Fruit Punch"
        cost = cost + 0.8
    ElseIf drink2.Text = "J2o" Then
        drink = "J2o"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Alien Blaster" Then
        drink = "Alien Blaster"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Alien Brains" Then
        drink = "Alien Brains"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    End If




    '---------------drink3-----------------------'
    If drink3.Text = "Cola" Then
        drink = "Cola"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink3.Text = "Fruit Punch" Then
        drink = "Fruit Punch"
        cost = cost + 0.8
    ElseIf drink3.Text = "J2o" Then
        drink = "J2o"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Alien Blaster" Then
        drink = "Alien Blaster"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Alien Brains" Then
        drink = "Alien Brains"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    End If




    '---------------drink4-----------------------'
    If drink4.Text = "Cola" Then
        drink = "Cola"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink4.Text = "Fruit Punch" Then
        drink = "Fruit Punch"
        cost = cost + 0.8
    ElseIf drink4.Text = "J2o" Then
        drink = "J2o"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Alien Blaster" Then
        drink = "Alien Blaster"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Alien Brains" Then
        drink = "Alien Brains"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    End If





    '---------------drink5-----------------------'
    If drink5.Text = "Cola" Then
        drink = "Cola"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink5.Text = "Fruit Punch" Then
        drink = "Fruit Punch"
        cost = cost + 0.8
    ElseIf drink5.Text = "J2o" Then
        drink = "J2o"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Alien Blaster" Then
        drink = "Alien Blaster"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    ElseIf drink1.Text = "Alien Brains" Then
        drink = "Alien Brains"
        cost = cost + 0.9
    End If

    ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(myformat, table, pizza, base, topping, drink))


    totallabel.Text = Format(cost, "currency")
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not `tableno.Tex = table` instead of all these `if..else`?!

Comment: Your first problem, this is not C#.

Comment: Painful to read the question and code.

Comment: Yes sorry, i noticed after i typed, sorry. should have typed VB ^^...and the reason why i done all the elseif was because with each tableno a number gets displayed saying which number table as shown in the code...table = "1" etc

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Its time for you to learn how to debug, here is a start (admittedly the guy isn't that good (he doesn't even use short cut keys - but it should be at a easy enough level for anyone to understand): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxR_ngGIpQM come back once you've debugged your code.

In the mean time here are some pointers:

a) Use Switch (or called Select in VB.Net) instead of all the If, ElseIf statements. For example this:

```
If tableno.Text = "1" Then
table = "1"
ElseIf tableno.Text = "2" Then
table = "2"
```

Could be represented much better:

```
Select Case tableno.Text
Case Is = 1

Case Is < 5

Case Is < 10

Case Is > 9

End Select
```

It still makes no sense to me that the table variable is just duplicating the Text property of the textbox, so you could just use tableno.Text in place of the variable called table. If you are going to be passing this variable around to other functions, then just code it like this:

```
tableno = tableno.Text  ' 50 lines less of code!
```

b) This is another example, see how you assign in If statements when you could just do the assigning once, eg:

```
If drink1.Text = "Cola" Then
drink = "Cola"
cost = cost + 0.9
ElseIf drink1.Text = "Fruit Punch" Then
drink = "Fruit Punch"
```

Its much easier to just do it in one line at the end of the If Else statement, eg:

```
drink = drink1.Text
```

c) Dont hardcode the values (Prices, product names, etc)! Store the values in a database or even a text file!

d) If testing a boolean condition dont bother testing if it equals true. eg

```
If cheese3.Checked Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using C# with switch cases .Code will be more readable.As far as I am undrestood the cost is not adding up for Pizzas.After the pizas check the code should cost+=price instead cost=pizzaprice

Also Edit the order of code.Pizzaone followed by base1,topping 1 ,drink1 etc  and a ListBox.Add .Then do the same for pizza2,pizza3 etc followed by a listbox.add

Comment: Okay, great. thanks for your feedback. Also when i run my app i have to click on the "send to kitchen" button once or twice to get the app working. is that because of the order of code?

Comment: I don't think it is because of the order of the code.Try changing the order of code.As per teh current code it seems only one customer order will be added to the listbox